# PHP - Deduct two timestamps from each other, display in minutes

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a mySQL database that stores the checkin and checkout time of a person in a gym. I have imported the checkin and checkout times in to my PHP script. Now I want to deduct the two timestamps from each other - giving me the time left. I want this to display in minutes.

This is my idea:

```
$checkOut = "2016-01-31 15:01:11";
$checkIn = "2011-01-31 15:32:35";
echo ($checkIn - $checkOut);

// I want this to display 31 minutes.
```

I have seen many examples on StackOverflow, but none matched my description and I couldn't reverse engineer the ones I found - because they use the time() function - which I guess takes the current time.

Comment: "I want this to display 31 minutes. " You cannot, since the difference between the datetimes that you stated, is somewhere around **5 years!!!**

Comment: Haha, I didn't even realise. I changed the first one, but not the second one. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php);

```
$checkOut = "2016-01-31 15:01:11"; // initial value
$checkIn = "2011-01-31 15:32:35"; // initial value

$checkOut_stamp = strtotime($checkOut); // Converting to unix timestamp
$checkIn_stamp = strtotime($checkIn);  // Converting to unix timestamp
echo date("i", ($checkIn - $checkOut)) . 'Minute(s)';
```

**IMP Note:** The above method will only work if the minutes are below 59, or else the hours will be rounded off and **discarded**. So if your requirements is showing the time in minutes which can be grater than 59 minutes `eg. 144 minutes`, then you'd want to just divide by 60, as follows.

```
    $checkOut = "2016-01-31 15:01:11"; // initial value
    $checkIn = "2011-01-31 15:32:35"; // initial value

    $checkOut_stamp = strtotime($checkOut); // Converting to unix timestamp
    $checkIn_stamp = strtotime($checkIn);  // Converting to unix timestamp
    $seconds = $checkOut_stamp - $checkIn_stamp;
    if($seconds > 0){
      if($seconds > 60){
       $minutes = $seconds/60;
      } else {
       $minutes = 0;
      }
    } else {
      $minutes = 0;
    }

    echo  $minutes . ' Minute(s)';
```

Comment: The `"i"` flag returns the date in minutes.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I am glad you realised that the minutes can be greater than 60 minutes.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$checkOut = "2016-01-31 15:01:11";
$checkIn = "2011-01-31 15:32:35";
 $time = (strtotime($checkIn) - strtotime($checkOut));
echo date('i',$time);
```

use this code

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. One question: what does the 'i' in echo date('i', $time); do?

Answer (score 0):

If you were fetching this record from database then you can simply achieve it using MySql function [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), as no need to use PHP function over here

```
Select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,checkIn,checkout) as tot_diff from your_table
```

Comment: Hey. I think this might be better to use. However, how do I implement this in my PHP Script? I need to echo the timestampdiff, but this doesn't work:

`include("includes/connection.php");


echo "PHP is working";


$query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,checkin,checkout) FROM activities";


$result = mysqli($conn, query);


echo $result;`

Sorry, I can't seem to be able to space out my code. I can't insert blank lines.

Comment: What about fetching `mysqli_fetch_array` you forgot about that